# Vista carga antes de los datos

Tags: ionic-framework

Buenas , estoy tratando de mostrar los datos al momento de cargar la pagina en ionic mi código a continuación les muestro mi código quisiera por favor saber cual es mi error:

Page TS:

```js
mport { Component,OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,AlertController,LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { PlayersProvider } from '../../providers/players/players';

/**
 * Generated class for the ProfilePage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

 public perfil:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
       public alertCtrl:AlertController,
      public _players:PlayersProvider,
      public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {
  }


  ngOnInit(){

    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    // Mostramos el loading
    loading.present();

    this._players.get_my_detail(4)
    .subscribe((response)=>{
     console.log("Perfil",response);
     this.perfil=response;
     loading.dismiss();
    });


}

presentLoadingDefault() {
        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });
        loading.present();
        setTimeout(() => {
            loading.dismiss();
        }, 1000);
    }





  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }

}
```

Y bueno en la vista cuando quiero mostrar los siguiente:

```html
<ion-col col-6 class="full-name">
        <div class="content-full-name">
          LOZADA CHIRA <br>
          <span class="name">{{perfil.data.name}}</span>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
```

Me indica que la variable data esta indefinida:
sin embargo en mi consola la repuesta es la siguiente:

introducir el código aquí

```js
Perfil 
{status: true, data: {…}}
data
:
address
:
"axaxacbhdcb"
created_at
:
null
dni
:
"70000052"
email
:
"allamosas@somossistemas.org"
foot
:
2
height
:
2
id
:
4
lastname
:
"Llamsas"
logical_delete
:
0
name
:
"Raul"
phone
:
"992825491"
photo
:
"59f8e51faec68.jpg"
type
:
1
updated_at
:
"2017-10-31 21:03:28"
weight
:
98
__proto__
:
Object
status
:
true
__proto__
:
Object
```